# Prove that restricted quotient map is homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ be the quotient of $\mathbb{R}$ by the equivalence relation $x\sim y\iff x-y\in\mathbb{Z}$, endowed with the quotient topology, and let $\pi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ be the canonical projection.

I want to prove that $\phi:=\pi|_{(0,1)}:(0,1)\to \pi(0,1)=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{[0]\}$ is a homeomorphism. It is clearly a bijection, and it is continuous by restricting the quotient map, which is continuous by definition. I want to prove that $\phi$ is a homeomorphism, that is prove that $\phi^{-1}$ is continuous. I have some feeling that $\phi$ is an open map, but I can't prove it.

Could someone provide any help?

Comment: Do you mean homeomorphism instead of homomorphism?

Comment: @edm of course, thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

First show it is a bijection.
Then use the property that if f:X -> Y is a quotient map,
V is open subset of Y iff f$^{-1}$(V) is an open subset of X.

Comment: William, i am asking about a proof that the inverse is continuous.